# Make element wider, then narrower when certain point is reached

Tags: javascript, css

To the point: Right now every button click makes content-div 100px wider. The starting point is 300 pixels, and **in 600 pixels, when user clicks the button the width should go back to 300 pixels**.

For clearance: I don't want the width to go straight to 600px and then back to 300px with the next click, the pattern should be like *click 1. +100px, click 2. +100px, click 3. +100px, click 4. -300px* .. Then start all over.

I have tried to apply the else if -statement but for some reason div-element gets wider with every click but when it gets wider than 600 pixels, the else if -statement won't apply.

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
content.style.width = "300px";
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
if (content.style.width >= "300px") {
content.style.width = content.offsetWidth + 100 + "px"; }
else if (content.style.width >= "600px") {
content.style.width = content.offsetWidth - 300 + "px"; } 
});
```

```css
#content {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
background: lightblue;
display: flex;
align-items: center; justify-content: center;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#btn {
width: 100px; height: 50px;
background: grey;
display: flex;
align-items: center; justify-content: center;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="btn"><a href="#">Click</a></div>
```

Comment: `content.style.width` is a string. You're best move is get the width of the element using `offsetWidth` and then comparing it to a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
  if (content.offsetWidth < 600) {
    content.style.width = content.offsetWidth + 100 + "px"; 
  }
  else {
    content.style.width = content.offsetWidth - 300 + "px"; 
  }
```

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
content.style.width = "300px";
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (content.offsetWidth < 600) {
    content.style.width = content.offsetWidth + 100 + "px"; 
  }
  else {
    content.style.width = content.offsetWidth - 300 + "px"; 
  } 
});
```

```css
#content {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
background: lightblue;
display: flex;
align-items: center; justify-content: center;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#btn {
width: 100px; height: 50px;
background: grey;
display: flex;
align-items: center; justify-content: center;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="btn"><a href="#">Click</a></div>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
content.style.width = "300px";
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
if (content.style.width >= "600px") {
  content.style.width = content.offsetWidth - 300 + "px";
  return;
}
content.style.width = content.offsetWidth + 100 + "px";
});
```

```css
#content {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
background: lightblue;
display: flex;
align-items: center; justify-content: center;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#btn {
width: 100px; height: 50px;
background: grey;
display: flex;
align-items: center; justify-content: center;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="btn"><a href="#">Click</a></div>
```